# What is the different between Scheduler and Strategy in Apache Storm

Tags: resources, scheduler, apache-storm, topology

I'm studying Apache Storm. I read the source code && developer documentation && JavaDoc && other useful blogs about Storm.

A question confused me a lot. Most documentation and blogs said that different scheduler lead to different assignment style when Storm Cluster assign a topology to Workers. But I confused that what is the role performed by Strategies in package "org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.strategies.XXX" such as DefaultResourceAwareStrategy and other two strategies when Storm assign a topology ?

In Storm example program, I remembered these strategies applied in method setTopologyStrategy() to choose a strategy when create a topology. So,what is the different between Scheduler like ResourceAwareSchedule and Strategies like DefaultResourceAwareStrategy in the task assignment? Which one is the real factor to decide the task assignment?

I searched this problem on google but it not have a very clearly answer. I wish I can get a reply as clear as possible to explain the difference of Scheduler and Strategy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Storm has a few different schedulers as you note. Some of them don't take the resources of the supervisor nodes into account. ResourceAwareScheduler is a scheduler implementation that can take supervisor resources/load into account when deciding where to assign a topology.

In order for ResourceAwareScheduler to be flexible, it uses a strategy to figure out how to rank the different supervisors. ResourceAwareScheduler contains the common code necessary to be resource aware, while the strategies do the actual scheduling. The ResourceAwareScheduler uses the strategy to do the scheduling, if that makes sense.

Look at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/scheduler/resource/strategies/scheduling/DefaultResourceAwareStrategy.java#L108 and the corresponding line in GenericResourceAwareStrategy. The comments there explain what the different strategies do.